# Firebug console stacktrace

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

How do I get a stack trace using Firebug's error console?

I've tried the following test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function f3() { console.trace(); }

function f2() { f3(); }

function f1() { f2(); }

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad = "f1()">
</body>
</html>
```

This test simply calls 3 different functions, create a stack 3 levels deep. The third function just prints out a stacktrace.  But, the Firebug console doesn't show anything:

```
[07:26:47.955] GET http://mydomain.com/test.html [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 23ms]
```

Is there something else I need to do to get a stacktrace working?

Comment: Works for me. Make sure Firebug is active before any console calls

Answer (score 1):

Interesting fact: when i run your code, i get the following stack trace in safari:

[image]

but when i run this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    function f3() { console.trace(); }
    function f2() { f3(); }
    function f1() { f2(); }
    f1();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the stack trace looks like this:

[image]

maybe some weird optimization going on here?